# Creating a prototype of play's controller and action to help understand scala

Tags: scala

I'm confused as to how the request object can be injected into the Action.

Was hoping someone could create a simple prototype of the following in scala:

```
class HomeController() extends AbstractController {
  def index() = Action { request =>
    Ok("hello")
  }
}
```

What I mean is, create the above classes/functions to simple return a string "hello", with the ability to get other objects in scope like "request".

```
abstract class AbstractController()
case class Action(???)
case class Ok(????)
```

I am just confused has to how you can create an Action {} and then have request available in the block specifically.

Comment: It could be suggested to first have a look at the various tutorial available around the web about loan pattern and higher order functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `Action { request => ??? }`, you're calling the apply method in the `Action` companion object. This method takes one parameter which is a function that takes a request and returns a response. The `request` value is the parameter of the function that you pass to the apply method.

[Here's](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder@apply(block:R[B]=%3Eplay.api.mvc.Result):play.api.mvc.Action[B]) the method that you're calling.

If you would write a class like `Action` yourself, it may look similar to this:

```
case class Action(f: Request => Ok)
```

Comment: The scaladoc permalink that I posted should point to the method `apply(block: (R[B]) ⇒ Result): Action[B] `, but scaladoc permalinks seems to be a little broken...

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a complete example to get my mind to grasp this concept.  It is still a little abstract in my mind.

Comment: that is perfect!  Can you break down what this is in detail please ```case class Action(f: Request => Ok)``` the parameter is f, which is a function who's input is a of type Request and returns type OK right?  is this passed by name style?